# Rails Development and Production environments restart requirement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

In Development when i change the views,controllers, routes, etc. There's no need to restart the rails server, but we do need in Production environment? Is it saving something in the memory so that we need the restart?

And about all the Gem files that we need in Gemfile (Gemfile.lock), are those Gems loaded (or save into somewhere) when we run the rails app, or is it loaded on-demand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of your views controllers and routes are cached in production to speed the app along.  It would be a very bad thing to have to reload all of those for every request.  This is taken from development.rb:

```
# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false
```

Also, your gems are loaded when the application environment starts.  Those are installed to your global gem directory by doing a `bundle install`.  When you deploy to another server, you have to do `bundle install` on those as well.

Comment: Thanks Sean Hill for your reply. But i've just found another thread about the gems [Gems Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329006/does-rails-load-all-installed-gems). @Justin said totally different to you, I'm confusing. Thanks

Comment: He says, "No, just those that you require or are required by Rails."  If they are included in your Gemfile, then they are required for your Rails app.  :-)  Basically, you can have 1,000 gems in your gems folder, but only those in your Gemfile (required by your app) will be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The `development` server can afford to reload code, views, controllers, routes on every request because your requests are the only ones going to it -- and it would take more time for development if *you* had to restart the server on changes.

However, all those checks require re-`stat(2)`-ing every single file and checking the modification times on every single request. That is a *lot* of system calls. Reducing system calls is one top method of improving runtime and scalability of a program, so the "common case" -- millions of requests to the same code and configuration -- is optimized in the `production` server. But the common case of a `development` server is constant *change*.

Comment: It does reload routes without requiring a restart.  I run pow on my local dev machine, and I almost never have to do `touch tmp/restart.txt`.