# Does Passenger load all available gem versions into memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

My RoR application uses 3.1.3, Gemfile shows:

```
gem 'rails', "=3.1.3"
```

If I list the installed gems I get

```
...  
actionpack (3.2.0.rc1, 3.1.3)
activemodel (3.2.0.rc1, 3.1.3)
...
```

Question: does Passenger load both gem versions or only the version 3.1.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passenger is a not responsible for loading gems.

Other than that, this is duplicate of: [Does Rails load all installed gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329006/does-rails-load-all-installed-gems)

In your case, Rails will load and use Bundler to load gems defined in Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks. Now the only question remains why the ruby processes triggered by passenger each show 700+MB Virt. memory when I run top. On a new setup server it goes only to 100MB. Something is being loaded, any way of telling what?

Comment: This might be of help: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_inspecting_memory_usage

Comment: passenger-memory-stats shows 700+MB VMsize. I installed the whole stack on another Ubuntu machine, there it shows only 100MB. So something must be loaded somehow. The 700MB show up immediately after starting Passenger.